# Evento no deseado al tocar el botón atrás en el explorador en paginas generadas con Jquery, Ajax y Php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Poseo un sitio en donde las paginas se cargan dinámicamente dentro de un `div` que funciona de receptor.
El tema es que al apretar el botón atrás después de navegar por distintos eventos que van sucediendo y mostrando información, la web se va a la raíz del sitio, en vez de ir a lo mostrado inmediatamente antes de apretar el botón atrás.
Ejemplo
Ruta realizada

```
index.php => Listado Vendedores =>  Vendedor x => Lista de pedidos vendedor X
```

Si en este momento apreto el botón atrás en el explorador, en vez de ir a `Vendedor x` , va a `index.php`
He leído bastante pero no comprendo bien las  soluciones propuestas. 
Habrá alguna solución fácil que no conozca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas con JSON anidados, de esta manera vas a ir determinando una linealidad de los datos que has estado teniendo de forma historica, el JSON que debes crear debera ser correspondiente a los datos y modelo de dato que estes regresando sin embargo su forma basica debera ser la siguiente:

```
historico = {
   "index":[
         /*TODO*/
    ],
    "Listado Vendedores":[
         /*TODO*/
    ],
    "Vendedor x":[
         /*TODO*/
    ],"Lista de pedidos vendedor X":[
         /*TODO*/
    ]      
}
```

De esta manera en todo momento vas a tener la información accesible, ahora para mostrar los datos solamente deberas acceder a la información del ultimo json con:

```
let actual = historico[Object.keys(historico)[Object.keys(historico).length-1]];
```

Con eso obtienes el ultimo valor, ahora cuando den para atras vas a tener que eliminar el ultimo valor y para eso lo haces con:

```
delete historico[Object.keys(historico)[Object.keys(historico).length-1]]
```

Para añadir un nuevo elemento solo debes poner

```
historico["elemento"] = [cada,uno,de,los,elementos]
```

Y listo con eso ya tienes un JSON dinamico que te permite estar obteniendo informacion constantemente y ademas te permite avanzar y retroceder en las versiones.

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, el tema es que en cada listado tengo botones y distintos eventos que se disparan, seria muy complejo a esta altura del proyecto cambiar todo eso. No digo que no sea la forma adecuada. Espero a ver si hay alguna otra respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo, si se que no seria facil solucionarlo, me suena a que quizas puedas creando vistas el problema es que te vas a llenar de archivos

Comment: Estoy pensando en bloquear el botón atrás, y crear uno propio en la pagina...Espero a ver si hay alguna otra respuesta. –
Nuevamente Gracias Ivan.

Comment: No te lo recomiendo, quitarias mucho de UX

Comment: No habrá alguna manera sencilla de manejar el historial?

Comment: Con vistas, si estas generando todo dinamico en una sola vista lo puedes hacer con el JSON, si quieres que se maneje lineal sin importar nada lo debes hacer con vistas o rutas

Comment: Hola Ivan, ante todo muchas gracias, lo que no entiendo es que tengo que poner donde decís:
historico["elemento"] = [cada,uno,de,los,elementos]
En este caso x ejemplo: Tengo este evento, como lo cargo en el historial?

´$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#VerCandidatosNuevos').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.NotiCampanaEmpresa').html('<i id="CampanaMensajesEmpresa" class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>'); 
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        listarCandidatos(2,0,0); //Listar Candidatos Nuevos Empresa;        
    })  
});´

Comment: Te respondo de una forma practica que puedes cambiar a las necesidaes de tu codigo supongamos que yo tengo una nueva vista llamada `clientes` y ademas de eso todas mis vistas ya estan estandarizadas con 3 elmentos, una imagen, un boton y un link entonces yo lo que debo hacer es lo siguiente, ya tengo un estandar de informacion que me va a decir donde va cada elemento entonces determino que mi imagen es la posicion 0 de mi arreglo, mi boton la posicion 1 y mi link la posicion 2 y con eso entonces solo creo un nuevo elemento en mi json de la siguiente manera

Comment: `historico["clientes"]=[imagen,boton,link]`